# Error updating elementary OS Juno from terminal

Tags: updates, release-juno

I use elementary OS Juno([juno](/questions/tagged/juno)) and I am getting this when I run update through terminal,

[image]

```
Err:7 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  File has unexpected size (98548 != 98544). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 104.28.5.44 80]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:98544 [weak]
   - SHA256:880c7b018cb7b3b15e7b5b4e874018bb3ffe02229eee079f2af44ec5c4731bc6
   - SHA1:4febfca82a3495510dcd05bcc8046c2ae5bb0f30 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:875620c0d073eb28481c5bcaccca3b68 [weak]
  Release file created at: Tue, 08 Jan 2019 15:32:21 +0000
Hit:8 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Fetched 5.893 B in 2s (3.661 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter/dists/bionic/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.xz  File has unexpected size (98548 != 98544). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 104.28.5.44 80]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:98544 [weak]
    - SHA256:880c7b018cb7b3b15e7b5b4e874018bb3ffe02229eee079f2af44ec5c4731bc6
    - SHA1:4febfca82a3495510dcd05bcc8046c2ae5bb0f30 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:875620c0d073eb28481c5bcaccca3b68 [weak]
   Release file created at: Tue, 08 Jan 2019 15:32:21 +0000
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Hi Lutfi, welcome to eOS SE. Your participation is much appreciated. I have made some changes on your post to help it get found easily and make it look better though your choice of words and format DO describe your problem well.

Comment: Same problem. I hope anyone to solve & share it. :(